# session lost after reloading in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-6

Here is simple sigin method :

LoginController :

```
public function signin(Request $r)
{
    $data['email'] = $r->email;
    $data['password'] = md5($r->password);

    if ($data['email'] == '' || $data['password'] == '') {
        echo 'Please enter email or password.';
    } else {
        $userInfo = DB::table('users')->where('email', $data['email'])->get()->first();

        if ($data['email'] == $userInfo->email && $data['password'] == $userInfo->password) {
            $r->session()->put('userData', $data['email']);
            $userData = $r->session()->get('userData');

            return redirect('/userpanel')->with('status', $userData);
        } else {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController :

```
public function user_index()
{
    $data = DB::table('personals')
        ->join('companies', 'personals.companyId', 'companies.id')
        ->get();

    return view('userDashboard')->with(['data' => $data]);
}
```

After login this method redirects to the user panel here display the session information. But if I reload here there don't display any session information. In my blade I print session by the following code :

```
<div class="alert alert-success" class="d-block">
   <div id="userEmail" >{{ session('status') }}</div>
</div>
```

I use it in HomeController and LoginController. But problem is not fix.

Comment: Can you add code of user panel controller ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the default login logic?

Comment: I edited the user panel controller as HomeController . @Amit Sharma

Comment: There is no reason. @Rwd

Comment: You might forgot to add use session in your controller please double check

Comment: I checked it but not work @Amit Sharmah

Comment: instead of request session try to use global session varaible. That might help you

Comment: check session timeout in your configuration I suggest default login logic. override method instead of a whole logic

Answer (score 0):

Using `with` you are basically Flashing Data To Session which will remain in session only for next request, that why when you reload you are not getting that that again.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data

This is `with()` implementation, in which it flashes data using `flash()`, which will be remain for just for next request.

```
public function with($key, $value = null)
    {
        $key = is_array($key) ? $key : [$key => $value];

        foreach ($key as $k => $v) {
            $this->session->flash($k, $v);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Change this code

```
public function user_index()
{
    $data = DB::table('personals')
        ->join('companies', 'personals.companyId', 'companies.id')
        ->get();
    session(['data' => $data]);
    return view('userDashboard');
}
```

Comment: So can you help me how can I handle this ?

Comment: @RusselMonzur try update changes from answer, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your blade file.

```
 @if(\Session::has('status'))
 <span>{{\Session::get('status')}}</span>
  @endif
```